# How to keep windows open after the execution of command finishes in byobu?

Tags: byobu, terminal-multiplexer

I want to run a series of commands (outside of `byobu`) such that each one gets executed and run in a window of `byobu`; so, I run for example:

```shell
byobu new-window "ping 8.8.8.8"
```

All good and working but my problem is that, if I attach to the running session of byobu and terminate the running command (hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>), the window gets closed too.

How to prevent the windows from getting closed and keep it open for further interaction?